# How do I handle javascript error in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using testcafe for test automation of angular based web application but my test is failing due to javascript error in browser console. I have tried to skip javascript error by using '--skip-js-errors' but it's not working so is there any way to handle it so test run without any error?

Comment: What errors do you get? Not all errors can be skipped. You might want to fix them on your web site first.

Answer (score 4):

If you are passing '--skip-js-errors' in the terminal, please try this instead.
Add "skipJsErrors": true in testcaferc.json of your e2e project and retry.

Comment: TestCafe 2.0 and newer versions also allow you to use different ways to ignore ONLY unimportant JS errors on testing pages (e.g., from third-party libraries or advertisement iframes).
Read more about the `skip-js-errors` option in the [Docs](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404038/recipes/debugging/skip-javascript-errors).